adding events to IOS calendar using pythonista
I am trying to use pythonista to add events to the IOS calendar. I am trying to use EventKit through objc_util, but I can't seem to get it to work.
I have tried searching up how to do it and used AI, but nothing is working. the code I currently have is
import objc_util
import datetime

# Get necessary classes from the EventKit framework
EKEventStore = objc_util.ObjCClass('EKEventStore')
EKEvent = objc_util.ObjCClass('EKEvent')

# Initialize an EKEventStore instance
event_store = EKEventStore.new()
new_event=EKEvent.eventWithEventStore_(event_store)
new_event.setTitle_("Test Event")
new_event.setStartDate_(objc_util.ns(datetime.datetime(2024, 12, 15, 10, 0)))  # Dec 15, 2024, 10:00 AM
new_event.setEndDate_(objc_util.ns(datetime.datetime(2024, 12, 15, 11, 0)))    # Dec 15, 2024, 11:00 AM

event_store.saveEvent_span_error_(new_event,0,None)

which I expected to add A event to my calendar but it didn't, and the code doesn't give any errors.
P.S. I have managed to give calendar permissions to pythonista.

thank you for taking your time to read this.

Since iOS 17 you need to requestFullAccessToEvents. For it to work, there needs to be a specific plist entry, which Pythonista does not have. Based on my understanding of the current state of Pythonista maintenance, I am not expecting an update.

hi @Mikael thanks for responding. I actually managed to give pythonista permissions. do I need to request it even though I gave it permissions? also I added photo proof that I did give it permissions to the calendar; in my main question.

I have not tried it, but based on what I read you still need to request it in the code.
